PHPickerViewController in Full Screen and Can't select Item on iOS 18
I'm using the image_picker package to select photo in my Flutter iOS app. It worked correctly, but it looks like the Screenshot. It can't be selected nor dismissed. This is my code:
        final imagePicker = ImagePicker();
        final image = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
       

I have tried to show PHPickerViewController in my own way.
                    case "showImagePicker":
                        var config = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
                        config.selectionLimit = 1
                        config.filter = PHPickerFilter.images
                        let phPicker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
                        phPicker.delegate = self
                        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(phPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


The result comes same. It's OK to present a simple UIViewController.
                        
                        let phPicker = UIViewController()
                        phPicker.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(phPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

now I'm confusing.

There is a bug on iOS 18 simulator(Rosseta)
